# cancelPreviousPerformRequest from background thread issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code, which is executed when a button is pressed:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];
```

The issue comes in when I wanted to cancel this from a background thread:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

I did this and it didn't cancel, it still calls timeout after 30 second. So my question, is there a way to cancel this from the background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), 'This method removes perform requests only in the current run loop, not all run loops.' That means that you have to call cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget on the main thread. Use performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: from your thread to schedule a call to cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget on the main thread.

It's a roundabout way of doing things, but should work.

Edit to show example:

The easiest way is to use a helper method:

```
-(void)cancelTimeout
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}
```

Then on your background thread call this when you want to cancel the timeout:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cancelTimeout) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I was thinking of using performSelectorOnMainThread as well, but confused on the syntax on doing that with NSObject? Mind giving an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer to call method after some time and invalidate if you want